# How to retrieve value using multiple autocomplete function for Typehead.js?

Tags: json, typeahead.js

I want to use typehead.js to have an autocomplete prediction with multiple result but so far i am stuck on the part which the data doesnt retrieved correctly.

I have tried other method which posted on internet but so far no luck.

I called this dbb.php

```
define (DB_USER, "XXXXXX");
define (DB_PASSWORD, "XXXXXX");
define (DB_DATABASE, "XXXXX");
define (DB_HOST, "XXXXXX");


$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);


$sql = "SELECT tags FROM wallpaper 
        WHERE tags LIKE '%".$_GET['query']."%'
        LIMIT 10"; 


$result = $mysqli->query($sql);


$json = [];
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
     $json[] = $row['tags'];
}


echo json_encode($json);
```

on my footer.php

```
var split = function (val) {
return val.split(/\s*[,;]\s*/);
};

var extractLast = function (term) {
return split(term).pop();
};

$('.typeahead').typeahead({
source: function (query, process) {
    return $.getJSON('dbb.php', { term: extractLast(query)}, process);
  },
updater: function (item) {
    var terms = split(this.query);
    terms.pop();
    terms.push(item);
    terms.push("");
    return terms.join(",");
},
    matcher: function (item) {
    return extractLast(this.query).length > 0;
},
    highlighter: function (item) {
    var query = extractLast(this.query).replace(/[\-\[\]{} 
()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&');
    return item.replace(new RegExp('(' + query + ')', 'ig'), function 
($1, match) {
        return '<strong>' + match + '</strong>';
    });
},
});
```

I can pick multiple value separated by comma but value seems only limited to the first 8 value from database.